# Finding symbols in libs in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

Is there a grand table somewhere so I can identify what LIB must be included for a given unresolved external symbol when linking VS2017 C++ code?
Alternatively a simplified library search utility would be great.

Comment: ***Is there a grand table somewhere so I can identify what LIB must be included for a given unresolved external symbol when linking VS2017 C++ code?*** I don't know  of any such resource.

Comment: ***Alternatively a simplified library search utility would be great.*** That is probably a  question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com remember that software and library requests are off-topic at StackOverflow

Comment: You can use dumpbin to collect exported symbols. I typically convert dumpbin output into excel sheets to lookup stuff

Comment: For reasonably unique symbols (and given a bit of un-mangling ) I find Google does a reasonable job.  Also to get to the point of unresolved externals you must have already included the header(s) from the library; so looking at your projects `#include`s is your 1st step.